# Associate app download with device? (Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform

How can I associate a user's device with my app? I want to have it so the user doesn't create an account but their data is still saved and retrieved to their phone so I need a way to associate their phone with my app. I'm using Parse to save user data.

I'm trying to use device token and I'm wondering if this is the correct approach. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
installation.save()
```

}

Comment: That won't work. The token can change in the future. There is really no way to identify specific devices anymore. Apple removed all public APIs (such as to get UDID) that did this due to privacy concerns. You may think of using the ad ID, but users can reset it in settings. Your best bet is ask your users to make an account. Luckily for you Parse makes it easy to integrate with Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: What about Anonymous users  from Parse?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use anonymous users with Parse. They've introduced them a few years because you can't get the UDID anymore and still may want to identify your users.

You can simply login an anonymous user on startup with the following command:

```
if (![PFUser currentUser]) { //we check if the user is already logged in
   [PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
          //user has been logged in
        } 
    }];
}
```

This will create an anonymous user in your userbase and they will be able to write data to your database. Anonymous users can be logged out and behave like normal users. There is also a possibility to merge them to a signed up user.

[Here](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/protect-user-data-with-new-parse-features/) is a blog post from Parse, with some additional information. Their docs are usually also quite helpful.

**EDIT:** in case you have trouble converting the code to swift, here is the equivalent code in swift (taken from the docs, available [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide)):

```
PFAnonymousUtils.logInWithBlock {
 (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil || user == nil {
    println("Anonymous login failed.")
  } else {
    println("Anonymous user logged in.")
  }
}
```